# Jest cannot find file-loader module

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, webpack-file-loader

One of my files have is creating a new Worker, and it uses file-loader module in order to do so.

Here's my code:

```js
    import * as workerPath from 'file-loader?name=[name].js!./worker';

    class VideoPlayerWorker {
      private worker: Worker;
      constructor({ onMessageCallback }: { onMessageCallback: Function }) {
        this.worker = new Worker(workerPath);

        this.initHandleMessage({ onMessageCallback });
      }

      initTimer = (): void => {
        this.postMessage({ type: 'WORKER_INIT_TIMER' });
      };

      postMessage = (message: ApeVideo.VideoWorkerEventMessage): void => {
        this.worker.postMessage(message);
      };

      initHandleMessage = ({ onMessageCallback }: { onMessageCallback: Function }): void => {
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', ({ data }: { data: ApeVideo.VideoWorkerEventMessage }): void => {
          onMessageCallback(data.type);
        });
      };

      destroy = (): void => {
        this.worker.terminate();
      };
    }

    export default VideoPlayerWorker;
```

The problem is when running jest, i get an error `Cannot find module 'file-loader?name=[name].js!./worker' from 'playerWorkerGetaway.ts'`

How can i work around this?